# DocumentDB pagination token. keep getting "wrong" one

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I’m having problems with the continuation tokens.

I have 16 documents and want to fetch 5 at a time.

This is how the request to the provided method works now:
1.  Fetch 5, get continuation token. 
Works fine. I get my 5 documents.

2. Use continuation token to get 5 more+ new continuation token. 
   Works fine. Get 5 other documents.
3. Use continuation token to get 5 more +new continuation token. 
   Getting the same result-set as step one + same continuation token as in step 1.

And it keeps alternating between these two sets and the same two tokens all the time.

Here is the code.

```
public async Task<Tuple<List<AdDocument>,string,int>> QueryWithPagingAsync(string continuationToken)
    {
        List<AdDocument> ads = new List<AdDocument>();
        var totalAdsCount = await GetAdsCount();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5 };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }

            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }
        else
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5, RequestContinuation = continuationToken };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();
            feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a=>a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }
            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have two different variables for `continuation` and `continuationToken`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Being a JavaScript/node.js developer, my tendency would be to write this recursively. You can decide whether or not to make another call based upon whether you got a continuation token back from your last call and pass it in for the next one. Null on the way in indicates it's the first call. Null on the way out indicates that you have all the rows and can return the results.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone The first variable is the continuation token that should be used, and the second one is the one we must return so the next call will get the next set. The code above is two metods merged into one for clarity :)

Comment: Cannot repro the problem locally. The continuation token returned each time from DocumentDB is different. (sometimes VERY similar, but always different). 

You didn't include the calling code for QueryWithPagingAsync so i wrote my own. Perhaps i fixed the problem by doing this. 

Are you sure that your calling method that calls this passing in continuation tokens is behaving correctly?

Comment: @RyanCrawCour-MSFT I fixed it here when I updated the question. I used to have the string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
above the feedResponse.AsEnumerable line. I will reverse the question to the erroneous one and answer my own question. Thanks for your helt!

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson yeah, that'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I moved the "string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;" to below the execution and now it works.

Working version:

```
        public async Task<Tuple<List<AdDocument>,string,int>> QueryWithPagingAsync(string continuationToken)
    {
        List<AdDocument> ads = new List<AdDocument>();
        var totalAdsCount = await GetAdsCount();if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5 };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();
                            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }

            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }
        else
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5, RequestContinuation = continuationToken };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();

            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a=>a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }

    }



public async Task<Tuple<List<AdDocument>,string,int>> QueryWithPagingAsync(string continuationToken)
    {
        List<AdDocument> ads = new List<AdDocument>();
        var totalAdsCount = await GetAdsCount();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5 };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();
                            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }

            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;
            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }
        else
        {
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 5, RequestContinuation = continuationToken };
            var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<AdDocument>(DocumentCollection.DocumentsLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AdDocument>();

            foreach (var ad in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a=>a.Id))
            {
                ads.Add(ad);
            }
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

            return new Tuple<List<AdDocument>, string, int>(ads, continuation, totalAdsCount);
        }

    }
```